# Playing sounds in sequence with CocosDenshion?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am developing a simple videogame using Cocos2d-x library and Cocosdenshion AudioEngine.

I can play single sounds using SharedAudioEngine's playEffect method, but what I am trying to do is to play a number of sounds in a sequential ordeq.

But I have no idea where to start. I've tried to create an action sequence, which would call the method using selectors, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The best way is to rewrite the sound Engine. It will be good for future use. By default, cocos2d-x does not support it. You can try to use CCCallFunc together with CCDelayTime to manually insert fixed delay in between sounds, but I don't recommend it.

Comment: I would start a timer callback at say 50 times a second. Have a list of samples and times to play each sample. As the time increases do a simple "if(sample_playtime[x] > current_time) playEffect(samplename[x]);". Also bear in mind you can play 30 samples at any one time with Cocosdenshion (I think it is 30); And remember to preloadEffect your samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    write number of Function equal to the Number of Sound effects.
    like this
    Function1(){
        CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->playEffect("Sound1.mp3");
    }
    Function2{
    CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->stopAllEffects();
        CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->playEffect("Sound2.mp3");
    }
    Function3{
    CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->stopAllEffects();
        CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->playEffect("Sound3.mp3");
    }
CCSequence *seq = CCSequence::create(Func1,func2,func3,NULL);
CCRepeatForever *repeat = CCRepeatForever::create(seq);
this->runAction(repeat);
```